# Align flex inside another flex

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm trying to create a mobile layout with a logo on the left nav in the middle and a chevron to display and hide the items of a navbar(I'm not interested in doing this functionality right now).

But right now I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
+------+---------+---------+
| logo |  lorem  | chevron |
+------+---------+---------+
       | ipsum   |         
       +---------+
       | dolorem |    
       +---------+
```

I've been trying to align the first item of the ul with the icons.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this while still maintaining the html syntax?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.main-nav {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}

.main-nav__list {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: flex-start;
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav__icon {
  height: 24px;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.main-nav__links {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.main-nav__list-item {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/*.main-nav__list-item:not(:first-child){
  display: none;
}*/

.main-nav__list-item--blue {
  background-color: #1c77c3;
}

.main-nav__list-item--green {
  background-color: #00aa00;
}

.main-nav__list-item--orange {
  background: #dd2e02;
}

.main-nav__logo {
  flex: initial;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/js/all.js"></script>
<header class="">
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <a class="main-nav__logo" href="#"><i class="far fa-user main-nav__icon" alt="logo"></i></a>
    <ul class="main-nav__list">
      <li class="main-nav__list-item main-nav__list-item--blue"><a class="main-nav__links" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav__list-item main-nav__list-item--green"><a class="main-nav__links" href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav__list-item main-nav__list-item--orange"><a class="main-nav__links" href="#">dolorem</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="main-nav__logo" href="#"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down main-nav__icon" alt="chevron down"></i></a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your `.main-nav__list`, add:

```
/* Add margin: 0; and height: 300%; */
margin: 0;
height: 300%;
```

To your `.main-nav__list-item`. add:

```
/* Add flex-grow: 1; and center items */
flex-grow: 1;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.main-nav {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}

.main-nav__list {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  /* Add margin: 0; and height: 300%; */
  margin: 0;
  height: 300%;
}

.main-nav__icon {
  height: 24px;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.main-nav__links {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.main-nav__list-item {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* Add flex-grow: 1; and center items */
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*.main-nav__list-item:not(:first-child){
  display: none;
}*/

.main-nav__list-item--blue {
  background-color: #1c77c3;
}

.main-nav__list-item--green {
  background-color: #00aa00;
}

.main-nav__list-item--orange {
  background: #dd2e02;
}

.main-nav__logo {
  flex: initial;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/js/all.js"></script>
<header class="">
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <a class="main-nav__logo" href="#"><i class="far fa-user main-nav__icon" alt="logo"></i></a>
    <ul class="main-nav__list">
      <li class="main-nav__list-item main-nav__list-item--blue"><a class="main-nav__links" href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav__list-item main-nav__list-item--green"><a class="main-nav__links" href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav__list-item main-nav__list-item--orange"><a class="main-nav__links" href="#">dolorem</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="main-nav__logo" href="#"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down main-nav__icon" alt="chevron down"></i></a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: thanks you so much! I realized too late about the margin. Would you explain the 
height: 300%; and how the flex-grow affects the size of each item? any link or resource would be appreciated too since I'm just learning flexbox

Comment: Reason for 300% is that you have a fixed width on the parent nav so the ul is 3x the height.  flex-grow:1; causes all the li's to grow equally compared to their content and fill the parent element.  Sorry I don't really have any docs to link to unless you want the w3c standards.  Just fool around in the Chrome console is my recommendation.  :)